# routing smpt from webserver to email server on different interfaces

Tags: sonicwall

I'm trying to route smtp (25) email from my web server which is located at:
192.168.4.4, 255.255.255.0
to my email server which is located at
192.168.0.3, 255.255.255.0

Note: every server is connected into one swtich.  However, my web connection is 
fed through a lag connection with a dedicated connection to x4 (dmz) on my router.

thanks.

Comment: And what is the problem ? They are not on the same subnet, so that go through the router, if the firewall allow that.

Comment: What MTA you are using? Postfix , QMAIL?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Route", what do you mean? Do you mean "I want my web server to be able to speak with my email server through the port 25 knowing that my web server is on the 192.168.4.4 255.255.255.0 network and my email server is on 192.168.0.3 255.255.255.0 network?". If that is the case, the only thing you need to do is to create a route policy in your SonicWall appliance so that the two network know each other. That is also in the case that both your servers are located behind the same firewall/router (in that case, the SonicWall).

Regards